# What religions were persecuted and disappeared (between 1000 BCE – 1 CE)?

Tags: ancient-history, political-history, religion, government, religious-history

R Gottlieb wrote in his book called "[Reason to Believe](https://mosaicapress.com/product/reason-to-believe/)" on page 66 that many cultures were persecuted between 1000 BCE – 1 CE, and none survived. As far as I'm aware, he does not provide any examples. Does anyone here know of examples (with sources)?

I'm specifically looking for the type of persecution that's long term, limited in harm (eg taxes, ghettos, attacked physically, expelled from geographical location, priests killed, place of worship destroyed etc)(this could potentially be felt by the victims as a PERSONAL attack on their culture).

I'm not looking for the type of persecution that is short term, potentially fatal (get killed or convert to religion X)(this is usually NOT personal, but rather an attempt to spread the "truth").

Some background:

Part of the structure of argument in the mini chapter in "Reason to Believe" is as follows:

1. 'Jewish survival is hard to understand naturally.'
2. 'The critic responds: perhaps persecution HELPED them survive (causes: makes them want to survive even more, stand up for themselves, show honor to family members who have suffered, and show their enemies that they will not succeed in destroying them).'
3. 'There were other cultures that also suffered from persecution yet did NOT survive.'

I am searching for those "other cultures".

Comment: I think the second section of the question is going to lead to a lot of tangential discussion, so it might be better to drop it as it's not required to answer the question.

Comment: What part of the World? The Mediterranean Basin? Middle East? India? [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ancient_religion) has separate lists of Bronze and Iron Age ancient religions by seven regions.

Comment: Two comments:  First, our knowledge of the ancient world is fragmentary even for the cultures that survived -- it's asking a great deal for any detail about cultures that didn't survive, since they are necessarily biased towards being marginal, small, and short-lived.  Second, the ancient idea of a religion is *very* different from ours. By our standards there were very few real religions -- the things back then that we call religions were different beasts and much less likely to attract opposition.

Comment: @pieterGeerkens ALL areas/religions would be considered good examples.

Comment: @SteveBird That might be true, but I'm specifically looking for Persecution Type 1, so I want that differentiation to be clear to people. Is that a legitimate reason for me to leave it in?

Comment: @MarkOlson I agree to your first comment. Can you please elaborate and explain your second comment?

Comment: @Tzvi K There are many books on that subject! Briefly: Most of the things we call ancient religions were in our terms more accurately organized superstitions: There are powers out there more powerful than a human and this ritual or that will cause this power or that to help you -- or not hurt you. There was little or no moral dimension to it and no one cared what you believed as long as you carried out the rituals. What moral dimension there was came from philosophies like Sophism, Epicurianism, Stoicism, etc. *Entirely* divorced from the gods.  Note that Judaism was very much the odd man out.

Comment: The first issue would be defining "a religion."  It was true that if you sailed from Rome to Egypt you would find people following the customs of their forefathers and having gods of different names, but many Romans would cheerfully identify the gods with theirs (Thoth as Mercury, for instance), and after all, you worshipped the gods after the manner of your fathers.

Comment: @MarkOlson Thank you for clarifying that. I will edit my question based on that.

Comment: "That might be true, but I'm specifically looking for Persecution Type 1, so I want that differentiation to be clear to people. Is that a legitimate reason for me to leave it in?", but that is **not** what you've asked for .  There is a mismatch between question & intent.  Suggest that you edit to align, to indicate prior research and to define the terms

Comment: I've looked and I'm thinking.  This isn't an easy question, for many reasons.   Superficially, what you've called "type 1" is what I'd call "persecution", and what you've called "type 2" borders on the definition of [genocide](https://www.un.org/en/genocideprevention/genocide.shtml). I've got gut feelings, but to be honest the topic makes me uncomfortable enough that I dislike even forming a hypothesis, let alone identifying which bodies of data I'd consult to validate that hypothesis. Then I'm left with M. Olson's observation about survivor bias.  Still thinking.....

Comment: A problem persisting is that I do not have access to the book, thus cannot be sure whether the argument is accurately on display here. While I do believe this to be probably fairly accurate (seen similar), it would be better to either provide a link to fulltext, or quote the necessary parts here–if length allows. // Big question: does Gottlieb give _any_ concrete example for either 'group',  'religion' or 'persecution', or does he let the reader fill in blanks with own imagination of concepts from allusions? Or: How do you arrive at your concepts? Purely own understanding from Gottlieb's text?

Answer (score 8):

Two examples from the Mediterranean and the timeframe 1000 BCE–1 CE come readily to mind:

1. The import from Greek into Rome, worshipping Dionysos/Bacchus, which had practices around their [Bacchanalia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bacchanalia) that were ultimately not tolerated in otherwise mostly laissez-faire Rome, and thus this cult/religion was persecuted:

   > Livy claims that seven thousand cult leaders and followers were arrested, and that most were executed.
2. A whole group of persecuted and now extinguished cults or religions. Literally: all other forms of worship than 'Jahwe alone', whether Jahwe *and Ashera,* Jahwe and other gods, El, Ba'al or whatnot, within the radicalising towards strict monotheism theocratic Israel/Juda/Judea. Source: The Bible, Old Testament.
   Much of the 'taking of the land' narrative  can be read as struggling against Philistines (and their religion), against Canaanites (and their religion), other peoples (and their religion).

   Concrete examples: quite many, here two:

   1. ['Golden Calf worshipping'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_calf), Exodus, Moses is not amused
   2. Prophet contest between Elijah and Ba'al adherents:

      > I Kings 18:40: And Elijah saith to them, `Catch ye the prophets of Baal; let not a man escape of them;' and they catch them, and Elijah bringeth them down unto the stream Kishon, and doth slaughter them there. *(YLT)*

   Note: like the wonders dealt out in that episode, the actual events and numbers slain should probably be not taken too literally as 'historical event, happened exactly as described in that text'.

These would be examples of the more systematic persecutions of others—and thus their religions— that echoed significantly through time.

There are much more examples when we also take into account more localised clashes, like rather frequent troubles in Alexandria mainly between Hellenised, Egyptians and Jews, or on Elephantine when again Jews (of a then still pretty polytheistic description!) and locals with their [Khnum temple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elephantine#Jewish_presence) disagree about who or what to worship and how to properly sacrifice things or especially animals.

All examples listed so far emphasise that 'religion' is not to be read exclusively as *our* understanding of 'religion', that is largely about abstract belief-systems, but much more as a struggle between almost tribal ingroup/outgroup problems, and [othering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Other_(philosophy)). The Greek, Roman and even Jewish religious leaders and followers were *usually* able to coexist and to cooperate, to tolerate each other. As seen in Greeks often trying to systematise other religions with equating *their* gods to their Greek gods, the Romans importing usually all other gods into their pantheon (with the big exception Bacchus and a little trouble with Isis), and the Jews willingly offering sacrifice and especially prayers in their Jerusalem Jewish Temple *for* the Roman leader of state (of course: not *to* that leader!)

A necessary critique of the original claim, that "many were persecuted, none survived". That is evidently untrue. The [Samaritans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samaritans) had to endure quite some struggles and persecution from their beginnings, and their numbers are very small today, but they're still around!

Further: If the notion from the original author should imply that most religions from that timeframe which did die out within that timeframe, *due* to 'persecutions', and not later, mostly due to monotheistic persecution by Christians or Muslims, then that is also a bit questionable. This violent suppression and elimination may have been present from time to time, but most changes in that timeframe were much more peaceful. On that subject:

— Michael Stausberg: "The Demise, Dissolution and Elimination of Religions", Numen, 68, Issue 2–3, 2021. ([Brill](https://brill.com/view/journals/nu/68/2-3/nu.68.issue-2-3.xml))

Comment: Ba'al was part of the [ancient Semitic religious pantheon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ancient_Semitic_religion). Their worship was definitely frowned upon in Judah and Israel (while it existed. Israel was in fact wiped from the map by Assyrian adherents to that same religion). And it did disappear in ancient times. However, that probably had little to do with anything the Jews did. Rome wiping out Carthage was a bigger blow for it. So nothing in here is incorrect, but it shouldn't be understood to be a causal relationship.

Comment: @T.E.D. I argue _ecce_ & _post hoc_ but not _ergo propter hoc._ Ba'al adherents were given a hard time in Canaan/Israel (look how often these are condemned in bible), _and_ he disappeared (so: _not because_ 'Jews killed all worshippers!') I  try to be quite explicit in emphasising that violence against most religions, because of that religion, did usually not lead to its distinction. Bacchus made a comeback in Rome. Ba'al was surely well after Elijah came & went…

Comment: Bacchus worshippers were not forbidden completely in Italy, but rather their political activity (congregating in groups, forming collegia) was severely curtailed. If they had a reason to make an offering, they needed permission. It's certainly related to op's question, but is more #1 than #2. (Also, Bacchic worship isn't really a separate religion, but a specific kind of worship within the framework of Graeco-Roman and in general ancient Mediterranean polytheism.)

Comment: I would like to point out that whether or not Samaritans are Jewish is up for debate, even in modern Israel. Samaritans themselves would say that *they* are the original Jews.

Comment: More than not taking the events of the Bible literally: it is unclear that there actually was a conquest of the Canaanites as such. Many historians now seem to believe that the Israelites were one group of Canaanites that rose to prominence and conquered the others, with narratives linking them to places like Egypt or Ur being a sort of mythic history. When one considers the relative ancient importance of places like Ur and Egypt vs Canaan, it makes sense that saying one's ancestors were Egyptian advisors or from a cosmopolitan civilization could be a good way of bolstering their credentials.

Comment: @MichaelW. Well, nitpickingly, they are saying they are the original 'Israel' (Northern Kingdom; Southern Kingdom->Juda->Jews), and whether or not that has 'merit', for this Q, they were certainly not happy when [John Hyrcanus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Hyrcanus) came along and razed Sechem and destroyed their temple on Garizim. That is but one episode that is historical, like cult centralisation after Josiah, which really put systematic pressure on all alternative 'places' (ie: deviant cults), which nevertheless continued for quite some time, but only Smaritans prevailed until today?

Comment: @LangLangC Thank you for taking the time to answer. Response to your critique: I think R Gottlieb does not mean COMPLETELY disappeared, but rather that they've EFFECTIVELY disappeared - that they're not relevant anymore (although I do agree that this is vague - we do not know how many adherents are required to be considered as "still existing").

Comment: @LangLangC Response to your final point: Part of the structure of the mini chapter in "Reason to Believe" is as follows: 1) Jewish survival is hard to understand naturally. 2) The critic responds: perhaps persecution HELPED them survive (causes: makes them want to survive even more, stand up for themselves, show honor to family members who have suffered, and show their enemies that they will not succeed in destroying them). 3) There were other cultures that also suffered from persecution yet did NOT survive. I am searching for those "other cultures".